# fbm & fbsr cookies and cookieless subdomain

Tags: facebook, cookies, subdomain

Found it kind of odd not to have found something for this already, so maybe I'm just on the wrong track.

But anyway...

I just set up a subdomain to store images, styles, etc., that, for optimization purposes, I don't want cookies sent to. Call it static.domain.com. I've got my own cookies working as desired by setting their domain to www.domain.com, but I can't figure out how to define the domain set for Facebook's fbm_ and fbsr_ cookies.

Is this possible? Or some other way to prevent them from being sent to static.domain.com, but pass as normal in requests to www.domain.com?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It’s Facebook’s JavaScript that is setting these cookies, and they try to set them so that their “reach” for being able to recognize a user is as broad as possible. The only way that I could think of to try and get these cookies not set for the subdomain would be to give the domain your app is working on in your app settings explicitly as www.example.com instead of just example.com (I haven’t tried this though.)

Comment: Bleh. Their reasoning makes sense but it'd be nice if there were at least an option to exclude subdomains. As it is, they've basically broken peoples' ability to have cookieless subdomains. I looked at the App settings in Facebook and thought I had found a fix, but changing "domain.com" to "www.domain.com" just caused it to stop working altogether. Oh well...

Comment: If it “stopped working”, which domain are you using for people to login from – www.example.com or just example.com?

Comment: Another thing you might wanna give a try – _again, without promising any success, since I myself haven’t tried it yet_ – is to set the `fbm_`-cookie _yourself_ before connecting to Facebook. They store a value of the form `base_domain=.example.com` in there – if you were to set that to `base_domain=example.com` without the leading dot there _might_ be a chance the SDK respects that value and sets it’s cookie only for that domain.

Comment: All logins take place at www.domain.com. I've set the App config back and it's still not working, so I'm not sure what's going on. I'm not getting the fbm or fbsr cookies at all ATM, so that pretty well precludes further testing for now. When that starts working, I'll try your cookie creation idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cookies are set on one of domains defined by "App Domains" in application settings. I'm not sure how exactly it behaves in case you list more than one domain but probably domain closest to the current one is chosen by SDK.

So if you'll set it to `www.domain.com` cookies will be set here and will not be sent to `static.domain.com`.

Also FYI it is not documented but `cookie` parameter of `FB.init` can be set to `string` value which is domain cookies will be set on. (I do not recommend using it in production before [official Facebook JS-SDK repository](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-js-sdk/) updated with actual code that indicates this is possible or something stated about that in documentation)